# Page tab , developer app.

Tags: facebook, tabs

I just want to use developer app for creating normal simple custom tab. And always get:
"400 Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. "

There is no syntax errors as u can see image below:
[Screen of configuration](https://www.cactusek.home.pl/untitled.png)

I did configured it as all tutiorals says:

Here is link for you to check that there is any simple text wrote in html:
https://www.cactusek.home.pl/index.html

So any1 can help me PLEASE!?:) 
help would be appreciate ! 
greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I went to that [link](https://www.cactusek.home.pl/index.html), my browser complained that your SSL cert is bad.  Fix that and it might work better.

Comment: Just try it use https://www.cactusek.home.pl/index.html without https https://www.cactusek.home.pl/index.html. Anyway i did tryin with https and with http

Comment: You have to have a valid cert for it to work.  It's a new requirement from Facebook within the last couple months or so.  Sorry.

Comment: I have no idea how to set it right it could be provider issue? or should i set it up on my own ?

Comment: You should work with your hosting company to get it resolved.  They may have to involve the company you purchased the SSL cert from too.

Comment: Thank you very much i will investigate those problem as u say :). Thx hope it is gonna help.

Comment: EHm i asked my server provider, they said its ok from their side. They have eShop that work on exect same way. So it probably facebook issue..

Comment: Um, when I go to your website, my browser says your cert is bad.   Facebook was not involved. "    www.cactusek.home.pl uses an invalid security certificate.    The certificate is only valid for the following names:      *.home.pl , home.pl      (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)"